# Proving Erdős lower bound for $R(s,s)$ and a follow up on graph colourings

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, coloring

Let $R(s,t)$ be the Ramsey Number for integers $s$ and $t$ larger than $1$.

I want to prove that $R(s,s)$ $\ge$ $2^{(s-1)/2}$ for $s$ $\ge$ $2$.

Also, for each $s\ge 1$, I want to find a way to colour the edges of $K_{2s}$ so that the graph contains no red path of length $2$ and no blue $K_{s+1}$.

Please can anyone help me out here?

Comment: Looks like you have two different questions in one post. Please make this two separate posts with one question each.

Comment: Since your first question has been answered, please edit out the second question and post it as a new question.

Comment: The second question is much easier. There is an obvious colouring with no red path of length $2,$ namely, take a perfect matching and colour the edges of the matching red. Colour the remaining edges blue; is there a blue $K_{s+1}?$

Answer (score 1):

Here is the standard proof that $R(s,s) \geq 2^{(s-1)/2}$:

---

Randomly 2-color the edges of $G = K_n$ red and blue, each with probability $1/2$. Then each $s$-clique in $G$ is monochromatic with probability $2^{1-\binom{s}{2}}$, and there are $\binom{n}{s}$ such cliques.

Let $X$ be the event that no monochromatic $s$-clique exists. We have
$$P(X) \geq 1 - \binom{n}{s}2^{1-\binom{s}{2}}.$$ 
In particular, if 
$$\binom{n}{s}2^{1-\binom{s}{2}} < 1,$$
then with positive probability our random coloring produces no monochromatic $s$-cliques.

Now if $n < 2^{(s-1)/2}$, then
$$\begin{eqnarray*} \binom{n}{s}2^{1-\binom{s}{2}} &<& \binom{2^{(s-1)/2}}{s}2^{1-\binom{s}{2}} \\
&\leq& \left(\frac{2^{s(s-1)/2}}{s!}\right) 2^{1-\binom{s}{2}} \\
&=& \left(\frac{2^{\binom{s}{2}}}{s!}\right) 2^{1-\binom{s}{2}} \\
&<& 1.
\end{eqnarray*}$$

To summarize, there is a positive probability that a random 2-coloring of $K_n$ produces no monochromatic $s$-clique when $n < 2^{(s-1)/2}$. In particular, there exists such a coloring, so by definition $R(s,s) \geq 2^{(s-1)/2}$.